# how to remove white screen when keyboard back

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, redirect, whitespace, buttonclick

We have 4 Text fields. After enter some data into text-field.We Click Add-item button.It's redirect to Next-page . But We Face one Problem.

My Problem

When We enter text into text-field KeyBord Will be appear.After Click Add-item button White Space Will be come and then Page redirect. [image: before buttonClick]

**After click button** 
[image]

Page Redirect Working Nice.But We Problem is Before Redirect white page will me come .When keyboard Will be go back WhiteScreen  Appear So Pleas guide me how to remove White Screen

Comment: Put the following code in a script at the bottom of the HTML page ( var height = $(window).height();
    $(".ui-mobile .ui-page").css("min-height", height+"px");
    $(".ui-page").height(height);) if it works, ill post a full answer.